# How do I add my bot to a Skype groupchat?

Tags: botframework, botconnector, direct-line-botframework

I built a bot, enabled it for Skype with the option for Groups turned on.

When I chat 1-on-1 with the bot, it works fine, and it appears in my Contacts under "Bots"; but I can't add it to a group chat, it doesn't appear in the "Add People" list and even if I type `/add my_bot_id` Skype responds with `my_bot_id can’t be added to this conversation due to his/her privacy settings`.

What am I missing?

(edit: I'm using Skype for Mac, is that the problem...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bot chat tap the plus icon and add members. This will create a new group.

Comment: For the record, the "plus icon" does not appear in the macOS client - I had to go to the iOS client, tap on the bot name in chat, and tap Add Participants.